# Sort by two fields but the second is depending on a condition in PHP

Tags: javascript

I have an array with "shops", each one has a distance property (distance from the user) and a "featured" property (the higher this value is, the higher they should appear).

So, right now I'm doing this:

```
var sorted = arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return b.featured - a.featured || a.distance - b.distance;
});
```

Which sorts first by featured and then by distance.

However, if the distance is too high (for example, more than 10km) even if a result is featured it's not relevant to the user.

So, I need sort them their "featured" property first but only if their distance property is less than 10.

I was thinking this:

1. Sort them by distance, put the ones closer to 10km in an array and the others in another array.
2. Sort the ones in the first array by their featured property.
3. Join both arrays.

But maybe there is an easier or shorter way to do it.

Sample input:

```
d: 19  | f: 2
d: 2   | f: 8
d: 3   | f: 5
d: 21  | f: 4
d: 6   | f: 0
d: 12  | f: 5
d: 1   | f: 5
d: 8   | f: 4
d: 5   | f: 0
d: 13  | f: 5
d: 11  | f: 2
d: 7   | f: 1
d: 9   | f: 10
```

Sample output:

```
d: 9   | f: 10
d: 2   | f: 8
d: 1   | f: 5
d: 3   | f: 5
d: 8   | f: 4
d: 7   | f: 1
d: 5   | f: 0
d: 6   | f: 0
d: 11  | f: 2
d: 12  | f: 5
d: 13  | f: 5
d: 19  | f: 2
d: 21  | f: 4
```

As you can see, after for the ones that have a distance less than 10, it sorts them by the featured value, but the ones with a distance greater than 10, it sorts them by the distance.

Comment: please add sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can just add a condition that returns what you are currently returning, and if that condition isn't met, return only the distance portion of it:

```
var sorted = arr.sort(function(a,b){
    if (a.distance < 10000 || b.distance < 10000)
        return b.featured - a.featured || a.distance - b.distance;

    return a.distance - b.distance;
});
```

Comment: Didn't work :/ I added the input and expected output to the post though